Make Auth::id() availeble in other midleware in Laravel 11
In Laravel 11 a middleware is called in the constructor of a controller.
The controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{    
    public function __construct()
    {           
        $this->middleware('NewMiddleware');                 
    }
}

The middleware
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;

class NewMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd(Auth::id());        
        return $next($request);
    }
}

The code dd(Auth::id()); is returning NULL. This approche worked in Laravel earier versions. There has been changes made by Laravel. Is it even possible to get the id of the user in the middeware?
It's possible to get the id of the user in the constructor according to this:
How to get current user id in constructor in laravel?
However I like to get the user id in the middleware itself. How can I do?

You should make sure that there are a valid session, your code is working fine on my laravel 11 app, except that you need to 1) alias your NewMiddleware on bootstrap/app.php 2) or give a full resolved name to the $this->middleware('App\Http\Middleware\NewMiddleware')

make sure that your route also has auth middleware
